# 3 tier programming chart

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, charts, 3-tier

I wish to create a chart using microsoft visual studio 2010 but I do not know how to do it. Tried googling for answer but none of them is for 3 tier.

This is my code for the Data Access Layer

```
    public List<AdvertisementDAL> displayChart()
    {
        List<AdvertisementDAL> dal = new List<AdvertisementDAL>();
        string sql = "Select * From AdvertisementRecord";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            _recordID = int.Parse(dr["RecordID"].ToString());
            _recordDate = dr["RecordDate"].ToString();
            _noOfClick = int.Parse(dr["NoOfClick"].ToString());
            _noOfView = int.Parse(dr["NoOfView"].ToString());
            _advertisementID = int.Parse(dr["FK_AdvertisementID"].ToString());
            dal.Add(new AdvertisementDAL(_recordID, _recordDate, _noOfClick, _noOfView, _advertisementID));
        }
        conn.Close();
        dr.Close();
        dr.Dispose();
        return dal;
    }
}
```

This is my Business Logic Layer

```
    public List<AdvertisementDAL> pieChart()
    {
        AdvertisementDAL dal = new AdvertisementDAL();
        List<AdvertisementDAL> dll = new List<AdvertisementDAL>();
        dll = dal.displayChart();
        return dll;
    }
```

This is my Presentation Layer(All I know is bind the data together)

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            AdvertisementBLL bll = new AdvertisementBLL();
            Chart1.DataSource = bll.pieChart();
            Chart1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

I guess I'm stuck in Presentation layer any help?
The bar will look something like this

Comment: you need to specify what do you want to show on x-axis and on y-axis, menas the name of properties.

Comment: On my X axis it will be number 1-100
On my Y Axis it will be the recordDate.
On the bar chart, It have 2 bar chart 1 is NoOfClick and another 1 will be noOfView

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
// Set series members names for the X and Y values 
chart1.Series["Series 1"].XValueMember = "porpery1"; 
chart1.Series["Series 1"].YValueMembers = "property 2"; 
// Data bind to the selected data source 
chart1.DataBind();
```

More reading [source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2009/02/21/data-binding-ms-chart-control.aspx)

I think here is a good example you can go through this link
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2009/02/21/data-binding-ms-chart-control.aspx

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraCharts/CustomDocument7787
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117998/A-look-inside-the-ASP-NET-Charting-conlrol

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2009/02/21/data-binding-ms-chart-control.aspxhttp://documentation.devexpress.com/#XtraCharts/CustomDocument7787 
the website doesn't exist

Comment: Hi, I still do not understand a single thing from the codeproject.com.
maybe you can help me out?